# Which keys to use to copy and paste inside CentOS guest on MAC

Tags: mac, virtualbox, centos

Which keys to use to copy and paste inside CentOS guest on MAC.

I am using VirtualBox on my MacBook Pro running CentOS 6.5 as a guest... I am trying to copy and paste some text in centOS (the guest) but it looks like everything I try just changes the window size

Comment: It helps if you actually mentioned what you tried.

Answer (score 3):

For that to work you need to install the vbox Linux guest support if you want to use it in desktop mode. And if your not using centos as a desktop and in CLI mode I would say connect to the guest using the terminal app using ssh. The terminal app lets you copy and paste the normal Mac way with cmd+c and cmd+v.

ssh user@ipaddress

Answer (score 3):

Try

> control + shift + c

for copy and for paste try

> control + shift + v

Comment: note that if right control is the host key, don't use it, use left control instead

Answer (score 1):

You need to make sure to set Shared Clipboard to Bidirectional as stated in https://www.liberiangeek.net/2013/09/copy-paste-virtualbox-host-guest-machines/

From Mac, you can CMD-C and in the terminal of CentOS you can middle button paste.  I haven't figured out the other direction yet.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried <kbd>Control</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> for Copy and <kbd>Control</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> for Paste (instead of Mac's Command button?)